# Why is my innerHTML being set to null property? That is, cannot set property of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var today = new Date()
var time = today.getFullYear() +'-'+ today.getMonth()+1 +'-'+ today.getDate();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = time;
```

```html
<p1 id = "date" />
```

**I've used this code for another task on this same HTML page and it worked**

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? The code as posted is not correct.

Comment: `time'` <-- Hmmm?

Comment: I checked that out already but my code follows it all. And, my HTML, css and JS files are all separate but I linked them in the HTML doc.

Comment: @Pointy. Sorry, I'm new to this forum. What specific code?

Comment: There's a stray `'` character

Comment: Yeah, that was erroneously put when I copy pasted here. It's not on my actual code, yet the problem still persists.

Comment: You should show your full code because the code here works. It could be that you've got your `script` included before your HTML is fully parsed.

Answer (score 2):

You have error in your syntax. Remove the `'` at the end of your js.
Also you can use `today.toISOString()` to format the date as 'Y-m-d'.

```
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = today.toISOString();
```

Also, `p1` doeas not exist. You surely mean `<p>` or in your code: `<p id="date"></p>`

Comment: Thanks. So i previously used the p tag for a getElementbyID previously. That's why I created a p1. I thought the p tag could be increased by p1, p2 etc. So that they can be manipulated or styled individually. Sorry if what I'm saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: So, since I've used the p tag already and used its ID. How do I manipulate this new command then?

Comment: The apostrophe you mentioned was erroneoulsy put when I copy-pasted here. It's not on my real doc but the issue still remains.

Comment: the p tag you can use as often as you want, just headline tags are h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 and h6. Any ID has to be individal like `<p id="date1"></p><p id="date2"></p>`.  What is the exact error and from where do you get it? Console? Browser? Errorlog?

Comment: The error is from the console and the date doesn't pop-up as output. I'm just trying my hands at different things because I'm new to js.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<p1 id = "date" />
<script>
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getFullYear() + "-"+ today.getMonth()+1+ today.getDate();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = time;
</script>
</body></html>
```

The p1 tag needs to exist before the script block is called, or the "date" element will be null.

Here is some code that can help with debugging.

```
<html><body>
<p id = "date1" />
<script>
var el_1 = document.getElementById("date1");
var el_2 = document.getElementById("date2");
alert("el_1=" + el_1  + "\n" + "el_2=" + el_2);
</script>
<p id="date2" />
</body></html>
```

When I run the second code, I get el_2=null.